# How to acces XML data in response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml

I have this method

```js
angular.module('RDash')

.controller("SipsCtrl", ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
  'use strict';    
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://192.168.2.35/SIPSWS/SIPSWS.asmx/HelloWorld'
          }).then(
              //OK
              function (response) {
              $scope.btnCUPS = "Exito",
            },
              //KO
              function (response) {
              $scope.btnCUPS = "Error",
            });
}]);
```

I have a server status 200 ok, but y don´t see the response.

I should receive XML data response with the next structure

```html
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hola a todos</string>
```

How can I put de response in my view?

Comment: did you tried to console.log(response)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you are really getting the data by: `console.log(response);`

If you are, the generaly comes a data inside response, in the controller:

```
$scope.data = response.data;
```

In the view:

```
<div>{{data}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support!